# My 2 week old kittens are probably ill

Tags: cats, health, parasites, poison

I'm having a problem with my 2 week old kittens. They have been sprayed by a perfume. Suddenly, they started to vomit worms and milk, too. And the other kitten has been dropped from a height, probably of 1 meter. So I'm worried about them being sick. What should I do? Are the kittens ill?

Comment: bring em to a vet? vomiting worms would have nothing to do, directly with the perfume, but is something *very* concerning. And if one klitten has worms, the others might too.

Comment: Take the cat to a vet for propery diagnosis and treatment.

Answer (score 2):

If the mother still takes care of the kittens, the perfume will not matter.

But, vomiting, with worms, is a problem. At the least, call the nearest vet, today! Better yet, bring your kittens to the vet. The sooner, the better. They will need de-worming. The vet will know what to do.

Also, de-worm the mother cat, otherwise she will pass the eggs to the kittens. And that will restart the whole worm problem.

And, take care of the little ones! The older they get, the stronger they get. But dropping a kitten is a big no-no. Healthy adult cats can handle 1 meter drop no problem. So, do be careful. If you are not sure if other people are careful enough, don't let them handle kittens. No matter how much they want it. Young kittens can easily be hurt of killed if you are not careful.